# TrayIcon display message pops a window in mac

Tags: java, macos, notifications, system-tray

I am creating a creating java app in which I am displaying a Ballon message in system tray / notification bar. It displays a balloon message properly in windows(the balloon auto fades away in seconds) but on Mac machine it displays a window(which has to be closed purposely by the user). How can I achieve the same effect on Mac?

**JAVA Code:**

```
trayIcon.displayMessage("Caption", "text", MessageType);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be looking to integrate with Notification Center on Mac rather than using the old popup style. You can use one of the third party APIs to integrate with [Growl](http://growl.info/) to allow you to do this.